# How to manage massive calls to Postgresql in Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, queue

I have a question regarding massive calls to PostgreSQL.
This is the scenario:

- I have a simple Nodejs app that makes queries to PostgreSQL in a short period of time.
- Everything is fine, but sometimes these calls get rejected due to Postgresql maximum pool connections setting, which is equal to 100.

I have in mind to make queue consumption app style, which means adding every query to a queue and then consuming an element every second. By consequence a query to PostgreSQL every second.

But my problem is, Idk where to start. This is the part where I am getting problems with, at some point, I have a lot of calls and I get lots of "ERROR IN QUERY EXECUTION" for the reason explained before.

```
const pool3 = new Pool(credentialsPostGres);
let res = [];
let sql_call = "select colum1 from table2 where x = y"; //the real query is a bit more complex, but you get the idea.
poll_query.query(sql_call,(err,results) => {
  if (err) {
    pool3.end();
    console.log(err + " ERROR IN QUERY EXECUTION");
  } else {
    res.push({ data: Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results.rows))) });
    pool3.end();
    return callback(res,data);
  }
})
```

How I should manage this part into a queue? I am a bit lost.

Help!

Comment: Is the real code creating and ending the connection pool on every query? That would be extremely inefficient. If you reuse a single connection pool you may find it scales fine.

Comment: If you do end up needing to throttle the queries, you could convert your code to use promises, and then use https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/throat to throttle the query function to a given number of parallel requests.

Comment: @ForbesLindesay I will check your suggestion. Thanks!